# Getting HTML(Readable) Format from RadRichTextBox using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, rich-text-editor

I am building an application on MVC, where we had same application in MVVM silverlight, we had no problem in using PDF's an RadRichTextBox formats, so in MVC we are using same database same as in MVVM, and here I am having some problem as below

```
in sql server database we have already stored a radrichtextbox formatted data, and using MVC I am trying to get that data and put it back to PDF(which is working fine in MVVM), and I am able to put it on PDF without any problem, but the format which get it on PDF is not in proper order or its not readable, below I am providing example of format what I have on sql server and what format I am expecting it from there
```

**My question**

Is there any way we could use that radrichtextbox format to convert it into HTML format so that I can use it on PDF

since I am using MVC is there any dll, so that i can implement to get right format

**NOTE**

I already searched in stack forum with no help, and I even contacted Telerik people regarding this all they were able to help me out is for silverlight

and This link from telerik [rich-editor](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/) will help me to get it into right format which I need but finding hard time to implement

So if there any one could able to help me or even guide me in this would be much helpful for me, Thanks

**UNFORMATTED DATA WHICH I GET FROM SQL SERVER**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\"> <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /><title>Untitled</title><style type=\"text/css\">\r\n.s_D8D99854 { font-family: 'Verdana';font-style: Normal; } \r\n</style></head><body><p ><span class=\"s_D8D99854\">&nbsp;hello</span></p></body></html>
```

[image]

**AND THIS IS THE FORMAT I SHOULD GET FROM ABOVE**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can easily strip the content by yourself using the server-side String.Replace method by converting all \" instances to "
If the PDF convertor does not understand the meta tags, the HTML, HEAD and BODY tags then strip them too using regular expressions.